# Why didn't 10th Doctor cut and keep a body part after regeneration?

Tags: doctor-who

When 10th Doctor first regenerated after being shot by a Dalek, he kept his body same (using his old body part preserved by Captain Jack Harkness) because he had *vanity issues* at that time.

Just after regeneration, why didn't he cut his hand (or any other body part) again (which would have been repaired in regeneration phase) to use it next time (Vanity Issues)?

Comment: Are vanity issues enough to cut your own hand off?? o.O I thought waxing was painful ;)

Comment: Wouldn't this defeat the purpose of getting a new actor to play The Doctor?

Comment: @DoctorWho22 Asking from in-universe perspective..

Comment: "Ok, so the Daleks are trying to destroy all of reality...but just give me a minute, let me cut my hand off, wait for it to grow back, store it in a jar, and then we can go save the Universe...not a problem"

Comment: More serious than my other comment: I forget what caused the Meta-Crisis Doctor. Would the risk of that happening again be worth it?

Comment: @MacCooper if I understand the question, he's asking about a scene that happened before the meta-crisis doctor existed.

Comment: @tilley31 He's got a time machine - he has access to practically, if not literally, all the time in the universe! He could, if he so desired, step out from the midst of an active battlefield, go take a year off in the Bahamas, and then return to that battle as if he'd never left! But let's not start down that path, because then we'll end up entangled in trying to sort out the wibbly-wobbly nature of time and canon in the Doctor Who universe.

Comment: @Iszi You forgot...the Doctor CANNOT cross his own timeline. Except when he can, of course **wink wink**

Comment: @tilley31 See, I said we didn't want to get into the wibbly-wobbliness. ***STOP THAT!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just occurred to me that The Doctor never needed to cut his body part again because his existing preserved hand wasn't destroyed after being used in the regeneration. Probably, that could be used again to address vanity issues.

Unfortunately, later in the episode, Donna destroyed it producing a new Doctor out of it (Metacrisis). By the time, The Doctor discovered that, his regeneration phase wouldn't have been active.

Answer (score 3):

The idea doesn't seem to occur to him at the time, so no reason is given for why he didn't do that. So there likely is no canon answer (for whatever that's worth in Doctor Who).

However, there is one major distinction between the first regeneration, where his hand regrew, and the second one: he intentionally aborted the second regeneration. According to his explanation, after using some of his regeneration energy to heal himself, he funneled what was left into the "matching recepticle" -- his severed hand. The implication here is, that if any regeneration energy was left in his body, he would have continued to change as with a normal regeneration.

So, based on that explanation, the most likely reason is that he **had no regeneration energy left** -- he was forced to discharge all of it, immediately, to stop the regeneration, so if he severed another limb, it would not grow back.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. Within the first 15 hours of regeneration, Time Lords can still heal themselves with the leftover regeneration energy, as seen in The Christmas Invasion. River Song did something similar in Let's Kill Hitler when the Nazis shot her: "Piece of advice, boys...never shoot a girl while she's regenerating"

Comment: @tilley31 but in those cases, the regeneration proceeded as normal, so there was energy left over in their body (presumably for ~15 hours). In this case, Ten specifically short-circuited the normal process in order to stop it from finishing.

Comment: Yeah, I think I get what you mean now. It was not a normal regeneration after all. I still think he had no time to think about that (cutting a limb off and storing it for future use), with the Dalek fleet and all, but it's a good theory.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i think that cutting a hand must hurt as hell...
Also, there were no meaning in wasting Regeneration Energy in growing ANOTHER arm.
It´s limited and pretious (I suppose).

Comment: Regeneration energy comes in packet. It wouldn't be wasted.

Comment: @SS Sure, each time lord gets a certain number of "packets" but the packets themselves apparently have a finite amount of energy. So, if you know that you can be effectively invulnerable from outside threats for a certain time (and The Doctor faces so many on such a regular basis) why do anything that would intentionally reduce that time if you can avoid it?

Comment: But it then it would contradict the fact the the Eleventh Doctor pass some regeneration energy to River Song. I find more plaussible the theory that is more like a battery. You can use it the amount you want, but there where one moment that you dont have enough energy to, for example regenerate, but you have some for small tasks like fixing a wristh. It's more "natural" and "biological", from my point of view.